# Anime Identification: The protagonist wears a comma shaped locket which can be used to summon a robot or exo suit

Tags: story-identification, robots, anime

Looking for an anime where the main protagonist wears a white top and a shorts, has a sword on his back with a red grip and summons a robot or some kind of a suit by using a "COMMA" shaped locket wherein the boy stands on a golden dragon..he has a fat short dark guy as his sidekick who has a mechanical robot too.

I watched this like 7 years back.

Comment: Of too a good start with some good plot details and when you watched it. Do you remember if it was airing live when you watched it or re-runs? Was the language in English or Japanese? Take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help us get a better idea of the story.

Comment: Was it definitely robots? Akatsuki no yona sounds similar with dragons & lockets

Comment: comma shaped things are usually `magatama` though they crop up in all sorts of anime

Comment: Did he wear the suit or did it fight on his behalf?

Comment: @Xen2050 Akatsuki no yona does not have robots

Comment: Kuromukuro  has some points but It isn't  too old. https://myanimelist.net/anime.php?id=32245

Comment: @riccs_0x Yeah, that's why I asked, if it was "magic dragons" or something else robot-like, but not really robots.

Answer (score 7):

The series is [Mashin Eiyuuden Wataru](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mashin_Hero_Wataru). The boy in white is the title character, Wataru - since he was wearing shorts, you must have seen [Cho Mashin Eiyuuden Wataru](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=1172), the last sequel series from 1997. Here's his outfit in the Cho Wataru series, and the robot he summons, Ryujinmaru:

[image]
[image]

By the way, the comma-shaped item he wears is actually shaped like a [magatama](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magatama), a type of curved bead that was a cultural tradition in Japan thousands of years ago.

[image]

His stocky companion is Shibaraku, who, like many of the characters in the Wataru series, has his own robot - Senjinmaru:

[image]
[image]

Comment: This is a great answer. Let's hope it serves as a beacon for other anime ID questions to get migrated over

Comment: Superb work! Its a great reference to id